# Determine if the Implication is True (REGARDLESS OF THE VALUE OF F(x, y))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Given $F(x,y)$ and ignoring whether or not it is true, determine if the following implications are true:

a) $\forall x \exists y F(x,y) \implies \exists y \forall x F(x,y)$

b) $\exists y \forall x F(x,y) \implies \forall x \exists y F(x,y)$

My answer:

Part a would be false because the second part of the implication wouldn't necessarily be true if all of x relates to at least 1 y variable from the first part.
Part b I am unsure but I think this is true since you are making the relation more broad in the second part of the implication.

Does my logic make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. In the second example, given $x$, one can simply choose the $y$ that works for all $x$.

Comment: Stated alternatively, the existence of a **universal** $y$ guarantees the existence of an individual $y$ for each $x$.  But the existence of an individual $y$ for each $x$ does not guarantee the existence of a **universal** $y$.